# Create distance matrix when each variable has seveal conditions?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, cluster-analysis, data-science

I'm trying to create a distance matrix of data from certain US states over the past few years. Right now, the data is in the form:

```
State   Condition   2016   2015   2014   2013
Alabama         A      1      2      3      4
Alaska          A      2      3      4      5
Arizona         A      3      4      5      6
Alabama         B      4      3      2      1
Alaska          B      5      4      3      2
Arizona         B      6      5      4      3
Alabama         C      3      4      5      6
Alaska          C      2      3      4      5
Arizona         C      1      2      3      4
```

Now in a normal distance matrix, there'd only be 1 row for each state, and then you could use `dist()` on the remaining numeric matrix. However, because each state has 3 different conditions `dist()` will not work, and I'm wondering how to go about creating a distance matrix that accounts for each of these conditions for different years. Should I represent my data differently? Or is there a distance matrix calculator function that accounts for my conditions?

I'm looking for a distance matrix in the form:

```
               Alabama   Alaska   Arizona
    Alabama          -       1          2
    Alaska           1       -          3
    Arizona          2       3          -
```

This is what the distance matrix would look like if, say, I filtered it using `df %>% filter(Condition=='A') %>% dist()`. However, I want to know how to create a similar output while also keeping the data for all 3 conditions.

Comment: Well how do you define distance in this case? What are the values you actually want to calculate? Tell us the desired output and we may be able to help. If you don't know what you want, then this isn't a programming question and doesn't belong on this site. You might look at other stack exchange sites like [stats.se] or [datascience.se]

Comment: EDIT: not displaying properly, so I edited the original post

Comment: Done. Original post contains my desired output format.

Comment: That doesn't describe what you want, that describes what you don't want. What are the calculations you would expect R to perform in that scenario? the standard `dist()` calculate the euclidean distance across all columns. Do you want to reshape your data so each condition/year becomes just another column you can take the euclidean distance across? It really comes down to how you want to define "distance" in this case.

Comment: So are you suggesting I use a `reshape::cast()` so that each column becomes something like 2016a, 2016b, 2016c, etc, and then just run the `dist()` on that?

Comment: If that makes sense for your application. It really depends on how you want to be able to interpret the distance in your analysis. There is no "right" answer here. You need to decide what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot your data to have one row per state and oen column per `condition_year`.

Then you could use any of the standard vector distance metrics. But you should pay a lot of attention on preprocessing, scaling, normalizarion, weighting.